# How to specify which definition to use?

Tags: typescript

I would like to use type "Element" in one of my functions.
Type "Element" is defined in a dependency and also defined in another dependency.

Typescript default chooses one of them and always the same. How to choose the other definition?

Comment: It depends on which one you import. Also Do share some code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not dependent which module you import. Actually No need to import any dependency to use type. Give it a try it!